# Problem with button and textbox in jupyter with ipywidgets

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

I am trying to initialize a variable with the text contained in a textbox when the button is pressed , in a jupyter notebook running python 3. However it seems that I can't access the value in the textbox during the button pressing event and store it for later.

Here is the code :

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display
button = widgets.Button(description="Click Me!")
inp = widgets.Text(description='Path:')
Box = widgets.HBox([button,inp])

def on_button_clicked(b):
    return inp.value

path = button.on_click(on_button_clicked)

display(Box
```

)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The `button.on_click` function returns None. It doesn't return the value of the function you pass in as an argument. Think of `on_click` as connecting the button to a function that has side effects. In the example below I use it to append to a list.

```py
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display
button = widgets.Button(description="Click Me!")
inp = widgets.Text(description='text:')
Box = widgets.HBox([button,inp])

value_list = []

def on_button_clicked(b):
    value_list.append(inp.value)
    print(value_list)

button.on_click(on_button_clicked)
Box
```

Answer (score 0):

Your value will be available through

```
inp.value
```

Please see [the documentation](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Widget%20Basics.html)

Comment: Yes I understand this but it seems that I can't use this value to initialize a different variable when the button is pressed